# Why in msvc++ we have _snprintf while other compilers allows snprintf

Tags: c++, visual-c++, printf

What "_" means? Why Microsoft adds this mark at the beginning?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Identifiers in the global namespace starting with `_` are reserved for the implementation. `_snprintf` is just a function that the implementation (Visual Studio) has provided. As to the rationale for that, Visual Studio implements C89, and `snprintf` is part of a later C99 standard.

Besides that, the semantics of both functions are different in the return type, which in `snprintf` is always the number of characters that the formatted string takes (whether there was enough space in the buffer or not, while `_snprintf` will return *a negative number* if there is not enough space in the buffer.

That is, to allocate a buffer just large enough for the output you can do:

```
int size = snprintf( 0, 0, "%s %d\n", str, i );
char * buffer = malloc( size+1 );
snprintf( buffer, size+1, "%s %d\n", str, i );
```

You cannot do that with `_snprintf` as the only information that the function yields back is that the current size is not enough.

Answer (score 12):

`snprintf()` was not yet part of the standard at the time Microsoft's C runtime began to support it.

Since the function prototype was not standardized, and the developers did not want to use the name `snprintf` (in case the standard later specified a different prototype), they opted to add a leading underscore to denote the function as being a Microsoft extension to the standard.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the above,

**there are proper C99 [`snprintf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93(v=vs.140).aspx) and [`vsnprintf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek(v=vs.140).aspx) available since Visual Studio 2015**

and they do not even trigger the well known unsafe function deprecation warning.
`_snprintf_s()` or `_vsnprintf_s()`, while provided, are "secure variants" of the MSVC-specific functions, with the non-C99 behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from a different return value in case of insufficiently large buffer (described in David's answer), functions from `_sn...` group differ from the standard `snprintf` in another important regard. If the target buffer is too short *by just one character*, the `_sn...` functions consider this situation a "success".

In more detail, if the target buffer is long enough to store the whole resultant sequence *but without the terminating zero character*, the `_sn...` functions do not truncate the result, do not write the terminating zero into the target buffer and return the size of the buffer as a result. So, in general case the result is not guaranteed to be zero-terminated.

In the same situation, `snprintf` will discard the last character of the resultant sequence and write zero terminator in its place. The result of `snprintf` is always zero-terminated.